# POST List of Objects w/ endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

**tl;dr**: *is it possible, with endpoints-proto-datastore, to receive a list with objects from a POST and insert it in the db?*

Following the samples, when building my API i didn't got how could i let the users POST a list of objects so that i could be more efficient about putting a bunch of data in the db using `ndb.put_multi`, for example.

From this comment here at [endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb.model](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/master/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L634) i imagine that it is not possible with how it is designed. Am i right or i am missing something?

Extending [the sample provided by endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api_post) achieved the desired with:

```
class Greeting(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)

class GreetingCollection(messages.Message):
    items = messages.MessageField(Greeting, 1, repeated=True)

# then inside the endpoints.api class

    @endpoints.method(GreetingCollection, GreetingCollection,
                      path='hellogretting', http_method='POST',
                      name='greetings.postGreeting')
    def greetings_post(self, request):
        result = [item for item in request.items]
        return GreetingCollection(items=result)
```

-- edit --

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [docs](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/basic.html) about `POST`ing into the datastore, your only issue is that your models aren't `EndpointsModel`s. Instead define a datastore model for both your `Greeting` and `GreetingCollection`:

```
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class Greeting(EndpointsModel):
    message = ndb.StringProperty()

class GreetingCollection(EndpointsModel):
    items = ndb.StructuredProperty(Greeting, repeated=True)
```

Once you've done this, you can use

```
class MyApi(remote.Service):
  # ...

  @GreetingCollection.method(path='hellogretting', http_method='POST',                               
                             name='greetings.postGreeting')
  def greetings_post(self, my_collection):
      ndb.put_multi(my_collection.items)
      return my_collection
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think you misunderstood. That was just how it would solve using the example that the endpoints docs gave. Actually i don't have a model with a `ndb.StructuredProperty` which contains another EndpointsModel.
Just edited the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now i got it. It definetly solves the problem. Thanks!